# Обособление определений

Tags: запятые

### Мне нужно как можно скорее отправить письмо, а то сойдёт с ума она, бедная.

Возможна ли подобная вариация запятых в предложении? Если нет, то как можно его [предложение] изменить?

Сомнения возникли из-за обособленного определения, относящегося к личному местоимению, которое, по идее, должно быть в любом случае выделено запятыми, но всё же что-то там, в душе, мешает с уверенностью сказать о правильности пунктуации, да и предложение в целом читается с затруднением.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы правы: определения, относящийся к личному местоимению, обособляются при любой позиции. В вашем примере, если не поставить запятую, поменяется смысл. Определение станет сказуемым. **Она бедная.**
При таком порядке нарушится не только логичность предложения, но и сама грамматика.

Ср.: **Мне нужно как можно скорее отправить письмо, а то сойдёт с ума она(есть) бедная.**